# Complex Mail Merge (CSV to Word, CSV to PDF, or Other)

Tags: csv, ms-access, pdf, ms-word, mailmerge

**QUESTION:**
How do you write an ifStatement for Word or for PDF to calculate multiple rows per matching result?

**USEAGE:**
What I am trying to do seems fairly straight forward and was very easy when I was able to use MS Access 15 years ago, but with Access being not a possibility anymore, I am hoping somebody has a reasonable solution.

**The WHAT:**
I am trying to generate Statements/Invoices from a CSV (or spreadsheet of any format) into a nice report layout. Let's say the columns look like this:

```
First Name | Last Name | Account | Address | Item | Description | Item Total
Jane | Smith | 123 | 111 Main St | Ice Cream | it's really cold | $100.00
```

This is super easy and I can do in Word within 10 minutes and make it "pretty".

[image: Simple Invoice in Word]

---

**BUT what if there are multiple Items per invoice?**
So maybe the CSV looks like:

```
First Name | Last Name | Account | Address | Item | Description | Item Total
Jane | Smith | 123 | 111 Main St | Ice Cream | it's really cold | $100.00
Jane | Smith | 123 | 111 Main St | Hot Dogs | all beef, all the time | $200.00
```

*I still want there to only be 1 invoice per person but not sure how to do an **if statement** in Word that would say "If there are multiple items per person, put them on a new row, then total them all together"*

[image]

---

I would be glad to have the CSV go into a PDF fillable form if I could get the multiple rows to work - I just cannot figure that portion out.

---

*Other options: I looked at OpenOffice "Base" but couldn't get a nice form for a very custom Report. I researched briefly on how to do something like this on AWS, but without any luck. I don't think Microsoft has anything like Access anymore*

Comment: It's not clear whether you're looking for a coded option - you don't mention any programming language or use a tag for a language... If not, this question is not really on-topic for Stack Overflow. That said, for the table, itself, you could use a Database field, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436460/mail-merge-multiple-id/51443072#51443072. There's no way, however, to include the SUM part of the table. So as far as Word is concerned, a coded solution would be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Word's Catalogue/Directory Mailmerge facility for this (the terminology depends on the Word version). To see how to do so with any mailmerge data source supported by Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Catalogue/Directory Mailmerge Tutorial** at:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html 
or:
http://www.gmayor.com/Zips/Catalogue%20Mailmerge.zip
The tutorial covers everything from list creation to the insertion & calculation of values in multi-record tables in letters. Do read the tutorial before trying to use the mailmerge document included with it.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, the field coding for this can be complex. However, since the tutorial document includes working field codes for all of its examples, most of the hard work has already been done for you - you should be able to do little more than copy/paste the relevant field codes into your own mailmerge main document, substitute/insert  your own field names and adjust the formatting to get the results you desire. For some worked examples, see the attachments to the posts at:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/9180-mail-merge-duplicate-names-but-different-dollar.html#post23345
http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/11436-access-word-creating-list-multiple-records.html#post30327

Another option would be to use a DATABASE field in a normal ‘letter’ mailmerge main document and a macro to drive the process. An outline of this approach can be found at: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/many-to-one-email-merge-using-tables/8bce1798-fbe8-41f9-a121-1996c14dca5d
Conversely, if you're using a relational database or, Excel workbook with a separate table with just a single instance of each of the grouping criteria, a DATABASE field in a normal ‘letter’ mailmerge main document could be used without the need for a macro. An outline of this approach can be found at:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2010/mail-merge-to-a-word-table-on-a-single-page/4edb4654-27e0-47d2-bd5f-8642e46fa103 
For a working example, see:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/37844-mail-merge-using-one-excel-file-multiple.html
The problem with the DATABASE field, though, is that it won't provide the totals you're after. Nevertheless, if you're going down the macro route, it wouldn't take too much more code to append a totals row to the resulting table.

Alternatively, you may want to try one of the Many-to-One Mail Merge add-ins, from:
Graham Mayor at http://www.gmayor.com/ManyToOne.htm; or
Doug Robbins at https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=5AEDCB43615E886B&id=5AEDCB43615E886B!566

**PS:** While I'm cognisant of StackOverflow's preference for the substance of answers to be posted here rather than linked to, the complexity in this case is far too great to deal with that way, besides which, one can't post the actual field codes or a document containing them here.

Comment: To your PS: In this case, the question should be vote-to-close as "too broad".

Comment: IMHO the question isn't too broad; it's clear enough. The real problem is that StackOverflow's limitations don't allow the question to be answered the way it needs to be.

Comment: "The complexity in thi case is far too great" is one of the definitions of "too broad". "Unclear" is a different close reason. So is "not enough information to debug the problem". If you know of a venue where the issue can be discussed "properly" it's always possible to put that information in a comment, under the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach uses the Mail Merge function of Word with the [IF merge fields](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MailMerge/MMergeIfFields.htm), two variables (`oldinvoice`, `newinvoice`) and the `MERGESEQ`field to decide if the header needs to be printed (only for the first record and every time the invoice number changes)

You will need to draw a table for the header of the invoice and a table of single line for the details. I assume that all the information for the header are replicated in every record as in your CSV. To insert a new field or conditional field, you will need to pick it from the Word menu or you can edit directly but {} signs need to be generated with CTRL+F9. Your template will be constructed like this:

```
{IF{MERGESEQ}="1"{SET oldinvoice"0"} "" }
```

if it is the first record set oldvoice=0, otherwise print nothing

```
{SET newinvoice {MERGEFIELD Invoice}}
```

set `newinvoice` variable to the value of `invoice` field of the CSV

```
    {IF{oldinvoice}<>{newinvoice}"--insert a page break-- 
and the table for the header of the invoice with fields placed"  ""}
```

When the invoice number changes prints the header of the invoice

Then you will need a table of a single row for the details with fields inside and in the end:

```
 {SET oldinvoice {MERGEFIELD Invoice}}
```

to assign to the `oldinvoice` variable the invoice number just used

and will be similar to this:

[image: template for mail merge]

You will also need to add more fields (as invoice number, date, and grand total). To test the example I put an invoice number and added two more rows for a second invoice

```
Invoice|First Name | Last Name | Account | Address | Item | Description | Item Total
100|Jane | Smith | 123 | 111 Main St | Ice Cream | it's really cold | $100.00
100|Jane | Smith | 123 | 111 Main St | Hot Dogs | all beef, all the time | $200.00
101|Paul | Klee | 321 | 222 Abbey Rd | Something | it's in the air | $101.00
101|Jane | Klee | 321 | 222 Abbey Rd | Polythene Pam | eating bags | $202.00
```

Putting all together is done by using the [Mailmerge function (Directory type)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-a-directory-of-names-addresses-and-other-information-49afe95c-dc99-4cd3-85c7-3a80869cff90) and associating the template to the CSV will result in a new document (that you can now print or export as PDF). Something similar to this:
[image: Merged document]

If you need the grand total you will need a new variable to store the total and find a way to print it before the new page break and the new header.